# Extract ID from the response through JMeter regular expression exractor

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I need to extract the session id and user id from the response through jmeter using regex.

Response:

```
\"SessionIdEncr\":\"TLGdqhQbxkEOziVJYXMD7Q==\",\"userIDEncr\":\"9xJbu+CGYN5RnnALeC8mKQ==\"
```

What is the regex for it?

Comment: What is your expected output, i.e. what do you want to match?

Comment: what regex have you tried?

Comment: I need to get this one TLGdqhQbxkEOziVJYXMD7Q==\

Comment: i have tried SessionIdEncr\":\"(.+?)" but it failed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In JMeter you can test/fix your regex using View Results Tree's [Regexp Tester](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree):

> The Regexp Tester view only works for text responses. It shows the plain text in the upper panel. The "Test" button allows the user to apply the Regular Expression to the upper panel and the results will be displayed in the lower panel.
>   The regular expression engine is the same as that used in the Regular Expression Extractor.

In your case create 2 [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)s, for session ID use the following Regular Expression:

```
SessionIdEncr\\":\\"([^\\]+)
```

Get the User ID similarly.

[image]

Comment: Match[1][1]=TLGdqhQbxkEOziVJYXMD7Q== is like this but i need to get \"SessionIdEncr\":\"TLGdqhQbxkEOziVJYXMD7Q==\".how can i get that \ in it?

Comment: @GracesonAlias use variable name later as variable: for example `${sessionId}`

Comment: @GracesonAlias I don't think you need the "\", but if you do, use `SessionIdEncr\\":\\"([^"]+)`

Comment: the regression match is working fine but that '\' at the end is not getting fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern:

```
"SessionIdEncr":"([^"]+)","userIDEncr":"([^"]+)"
```

Not much to explain about the regex pattern, other than perhaps that `([^"]+)` uses a trick to capture the values.  It proceeds only so long as it doesn't capture another double quote, which would mean the closing quote for that key/value pair.

This would capture the base 64 encoded session ID and user ID, and would make them available in the extractor template as `$1$` and `$2$`.

### Demo

Comment: {"d":"{\"instrumentationLog\":null,\"userID\":0,\"sessionID\":0,\"roleID\":0,\"ipAddress\":\"106.00.10.62\",\"PwdExpiryDays\":0,\"projectID\":1,\"SessionIdEncr\":\"TLGdqhQbxkEOziVJYXMD7Q==\",\"userIDEncr\":\"9xJbu+CGYN5RnnALeC8mKQ==\",\"ErrorCode\":\"13\"}"}

Comment: Try escaping all the double quotes, though I would expect this not to be necessary.

Comment: I can't load your demo link, the link seems to be broken.  In any case, I've done as much as I can do; my demo is working, which means that if it doesn't work for you, you might have a problem with your data.

Comment: your demo is working fine.but when i add the whole request the matching is 0.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns this text
2. Configure it like:

   - Name of created variable: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
   - Regular Expression: `\\"SessionIdEncr\\":\\"(.+?)",\\"userIDEncr\\":\\"(.+?)"`

     Other fields can be left blank

     [image: JMeter Regular Expressions Extract 2 variables]
3. You will be able to refer SessionID as `${id_g1}` and `UserId` as `${id_g2}` where required

   [image: JMeter Regex for several matches]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables)